# Email Address Spoofed

Tags: email-spoofing

Starting this morning at 9:30 am I started receiving numerous emails in my AOL account thanking me for registering at their website and asking me to confirm my registration.  I am not opening them at all and are just moving to SPAM. They are coming from inside the US as well as worldwide and now total many many hundreds and are coming every few minutes.  There is nothing suspicious in my sent items folder. What can I do other than shutting down this AOL email account and start using gmail?

Again this is an AOL account but I am providing an alternative gmail account for your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Shutting down AOL account is not going to do any good for you. It could happen for your gmail account too. You should find out root cause.

1. If you are suddenly getting "spam bombed", it has been suggested that you check any accounts such as PayPal, Amazon, eBay etc. where you may have money.  Sometimes spam bombers do this in the hope that you will miss emails from these types of accounts informing you of a withdrawal/theft of funds.
2. You should report the emails as "SPAM" to AOL
3. It Might be a good time to check your account security.
4. Finally, account security is your responsibility; so you should make sure that you do not provide your email address in random places.